# In JavaScript, is it possible to bypass a setter?

Tags: javascript, prototype, getter-setter

I have an object `o` with prototype `p`:

```
var p = {}
var o = Object.create(p)
```

It is possible to add a property `a` to the object `o`, and then add a setter of the same name to the prototype `p`:

```
o.a = 1
Object.defineProperty(p, 'a', {set: function(value) {}});

console.log(o.a);  // 1
```

However, if we try to add the property *after* the setter, it is not added to `o` - the setter is called instead:

```
Object.defineProperty(p, 'a', {set: function(value) {}});
o.a = 1

console.log(o.a);  // undefined
```

Is it possible to define the setter first, but then bypass it to add the property `a` directly to `o`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `defineProperty` again and set `writable` to `true`. You'll probably also want to set `enumerable` and `configurable` since they default to `false`. You don't need to set the `value` as that defaults to `undefined`, but I think it's clearer with it.

```js
var p = {}
var o = Object.create(p)
Object.defineProperty(p, 'a', {set: function(value) {console.log("value:", value)}})

o.a = "test" // logs "value: test"

// override setter
Object.defineProperty(o, 'a', {value:undefined, writable:true, enumerable:true, configurable:true})

console.log(o.a);  // undefined

o.a = 1
console.log(o.a);  // 1
console.log(Object.keys(o))
```

Comment: Thanks. `Object.defineProperty(o, 'a', {value: 1});` is sufficient for my needs right now, but it's good to see such a thorough answer.